# Ruby on Rails: Bad connection with PG after running rake:db migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql

Recently I forked and cloned a repo I am contributing to and when I run `rails s` I get no errors, however when I run `rake db:migrate` I get this.

```
    rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:910:in `initialize'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/taimurknaziri/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I checked out some other threads with other people who had the same problem however their solutions did not really have any luck for me.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling PG as well as getting rid of the .PID file however it doesn't look like I seem to have one.

Any clues, pointers or advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thd error asks 'is the server running on...' - well, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means either your `database.yml` file in `config/` directory is not set up correctly for your environment, most likely `development` as it is the default or you do not have `postgresql` running.

If you do not have `postgresql` running either install it or start it up. You can check postgresql, more than likely with either:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

or
    ps -ef | grep postgres

If you do have `postgresql` running, then check your `database.yml` file and edit it appropriately, most likely something like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database_name
  host: localhost
  username: user_name
  password: password
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the database.yml, it was not configured correctly.